# showing null rows using join

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join, join

In mysql i m selecting from a table shouts 
having a foreign key to another table named "roleuser" 
with the matching column as **user_id**

**Now the user_id column in the shouts table for some rows is null**
(not actually null but with no inserts in mysql)

How to show all the rows of the shouts table either with user_id null or not

I m executing the sql statement

```
SELECT s.*, r.firstname, r.lastname
FROM shouts s left join roleuser r where r.user_id = s.user_id limit 50;
```

which does not executes and shows

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where r.user_id = s.user_id limit 50' at line 2
```

but using inner join the sql executes which shows rows 
which only have user_id values in the shouts table. the nulls are not shown.

```
SELECT s.*, r.firstname, r.lastname
FROM shouts s inner join roleuser r where r.user_id = s.user_id limit 50;
```

How can i show all the rows from the shouts table and null values in the
firstname and lastname columns where the user_id is null in the shouts table.
If not at all possible with sql may be using stored procedures...

Thanks

Pradyut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an `ON` clause in your join.

```
SELECT s.*, r.firstname, r.lastname
FROM  roleuser r 
  LEFT JOIN shouts s 
    ON s.user_id = r.user_id 
WHERE
    r.firstname like '%byron%' -- where clause goes here..

LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Does this address "How to show all the rows of the shouts table either with user_id null or not" - see my answer below.

Comment: "You want an ON clause in your join" -- alternatively the `NATURAL` qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want

```
SELECT s.*, r.firstname, r.lastname 
FROM shouts s left join roleuser r ON r.user_id = s.user_id limit 50;
```

You were using `WHERE` instead of `ON`.

Your second query worked because

```
SELECT s.*, r.firstname, r.lastname 
FROM shouts s inner join roleuser r where r.user_id = s.user_id limit 50;
```

just happens to give the same results as

```
SELECT s.*, r.firstname, r.lastname 
FROM shouts s inner join roleuser r ON r.user_id = s.user_id limit 50;
```

even though they mean slightly different things. For an INNER JOIN, the `ON` is optional and if you leave it off you get the Cartesian product of all the rows in the first table and all the rows in the second table, then your `WHERE` clause filters out all the mismatched rows. If you put the condition in the `ON` clause instead, the join evaluates to only the matched rows and you don't need to put a condition in your `WHERE` clause. In either case the results are identical for an inner join.

However an outer join has no equivalent `WHERE` clause equivalent, so its `ON` clause is not optional.